How to get the diamond on Siebel erd?

I'm trying to recreate this image, however I can't find the diamond option between the relationships of the entities. How can I do this?
I've tried going through the relationship properties and settings. I also tried changing the properties of the entities but nothing is working.

Just had to unclick the transferable option when the relationship between the entities is clicked.
